# Adding rows with encoding to a Google Sheet R package googlesheets

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, package

I'm using this amazing package to be able to read and upload data with my shiny app. It's working ok, but when I add a row to the sheet, it does not keep the same encoding from server, neither behaves like the data in the previous rows. Spanish names I manually entered are OK, but when I use the app to load data, special latin characters (UTF-8) are replaced in the sheet.
That data, is not recognized by the app in the following sessions.

```
library(googlesheets)

table <- "Reportes"

saveData <- function(data) {
  # Grab the Google Sheet
  sheet <- gs_title(table)
  # Add the data as a new row
  gs_add_row(sheet, input = data)
}

loadData <- function() {
   # Grab the Google Sheet
   sheet <- gs_title(table)
   # Read the data
   gs_read_csv(sheet)
}
```

Then, I use a button in the UI, and an observer in the SERVER to load the data...

```
  observeEvent(input$enviar, {
     exit <- input$enviar
     if (exit==1){

      addData <- c( as.character(input$fecha),
                   as.character(input$local),
                   as.character(input$dpto),
                   as.character(input$estado),
                   as.character(input$fsiembra),
                   as.character(input$ref), 
                   as.character(loc$lat[loc$Departamento==input$dpto & loc$Localidad==input$local]), 
                   as.character(loc$long[loc$Departamento==input$dpto & loc$Localidad==input$local]),
                   as.character(getZafra(input$fecha)))

      saveData(addData)

      d <- loadData()

      reset('fecha')
      reset('dpto')
      reset('local')
      reset('estado')
      reset('fsiembra')
      reset('ref')
      reset('pass')

      disable('enviar')

    } 

})
```

Please... if anyone can help I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I needed to encode the character vector before uploding...

I used:

```
Encoding(addData) = "latin1"
saveData(addData)
```

and worked just fine!.